# How to stop other code from running until setTimeout() finishes running?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, event-listener

I am making a simple memory card game. If you click on two cards in a row that are the same they stay open. If you click on two cards in a row that are not the same they both close in 1.5s. For that I use setTimeout(); However, if during that 1.5s user clicks on any other card, event listener function starts running again while setTimeout have not finished running for the first time. This crashes the game. How to prevent other code from running until setTimeout finishes running for the first time? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.container__small');
let hasFlippedCard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;
let lockBoard = false;

cards.forEach(function (card) {
  return card.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
});

function flipCard(){
  this.classList.add('flip');
  if(!hasFlippedCard){ 
    //first click
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;
  }else {
    //second click
    hasFlippedCard = false;
    secondCard = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(firstCard.dataset.framework !== secondCard.dataset.framework ){
        firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
        secondCard.classList.remove('flip');
      }
    }, 1500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a flag as part of your game state whether any cards are currently open and new flips should be allowed. Check for that in your click listener.

Comment: give the cards an attribute of `disabled` in the setTimeout function.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Not really. How could you put the click handler inside the timeout?

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure what you mean. The answers on that question discuss using Promises, Deferreds, and callbacks. Nothing about moving code into a timeout?

Comment: @HereticMonkey The answers there discuss moving code into a callback. What would that callback be here, and what code would you move? No, the OP does not want to have anything execute after the timeout is finished, he wants to *ignore* clicks *while* the timeout is active.

Comment: Okay, well, I was going by the question asked in the title and the second-to-last question in the text. Perhaps instead of arguing with me, your time might be better spent editing those to reflect the real question asked?

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent JavaScript code to run while your setTimeout() is waiting. This is the essence of the JavaScript run-to-completion/event loop execution model.

In your case you should have an additional flag to not do anything during that time:

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.container__small');
let hasFlippedCard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;
let lockBoard = false;  // <<< use this flag

cards.forEach(function (card) {
  return card.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
});

function flipCard(){
  if(lockBoard) return;  // <<< check flag
  this.classList.add('flip');
  if(!hasFlippedCard){ 
    //first click
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;
  }else {
    //second click
    hasFlippedCard = false;
    secondCard = this;
    lockBoard = true; // <<< set flag
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(firstCard.dataset.framework !== secondCard.dataset.framework ){
        firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
        secondCard.classList.remove('flip');
      }
      lockBoard = false;  // <<< unset flag
    }, 1500);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function flipCard(){
  if (lockBoard) {
    return
  }
....
```

end in your setTimeout function

```
lockBoard = true
setTimeout(function(){
  ....
  lockBoard = false
}, 1500)
```

Comment: Not exactly. You'd need to lock the board only when the second care is selected, right before entering the timeout.

Comment: yes I edited the answer, I put the true value before the timeout. Thank you

Comment: I didn't repeat the if else condition, I only added the missing parts

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: disable the cards before the setTimeout function and re-enable them after the function executes.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.container__small').addAttribute("disabled",true);

setTimeout(function(){
      if(firstCard.dataset.framework !== secondCard.dataset.framework ){
        firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
        secondCard.classList.remove('flip');
      }

      document.querySelectorAll('.container__small').removeAttribute("disabled");
    }, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` returns a positive integer that identifies the timer created by `setTimeout` so if you have something like:

```
var myTimer = setTimeout(function(){
  console.log( 'executed' );
}, 1500);
```

You can use `clearTimeout( timeoutId )` where `timeoutId` is the value of  `myTimer` so something like `clearTimeout( myTimer )` will cancel the execution of that timer if hasn't been executed.

So something like:

```
var myTimer = setTimeout(function(){
  console.log( 'executed' );
}, 1500);

if ( myTimerId ) {
    clearTimeout( myTimerId );
}
```

The code that is inside of the `if` block can be placed inside of an event listener like a `click` as the one above so you can cancel the timer when the event has been clicked again.

Comment: Please take time to proofread your answers. You've got three different spellings for the `setTimeout` function, only one of which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean flag to determine if the timeout is in progress and then don't execute your callback if it is true.

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.container__small');
let cardIsFlipping = false;
let hasFlippedCard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;
let lockBoard = false;

cards.forEach(function (card) {
  return card.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
});

function flipCard(){
  if(cardIsFlipping) {
     return;
  }

  this.classList.add('flip');
  if(!hasFlippedCard){ 
    //first click
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;
  }else {
    //second click
    hasFlippedCard = false;
    secondCard = this;
    cardIsFlipping = true;
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      if(firstCard.dataset.framework !== secondCard.dataset.framework ){
        firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
        secondCard.classList.remove('flip');
      }
      cardIsFlipping = false;
    }, 1500);
  }
}
```

Comment: You never do anything with `lockBoard`?